# How many requests can GAE Datastore handle simultaneously?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

So I have 25,000 .py scripts running at the same time every 2 minutes as CRON jobs (distributed equally over 1000 servers)

They all have to access the same DB at the same time, ONLY to READ from db, not to write.

So I was wondering if Google Datastore (for example) could handle this? 25000 requests to the same DB at the same time just to read?

I couldnt find this in Google's docs.

Best Regards

Comment: Your question would best be asked on their product support forums. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine/topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike traditional databases, which have separate distinct "instances", Google Datastore is a single huge data storage, which has no explicit per-application limit on the number of requests that it can process. Your requests go the same route as all requests from all the other apps that use the Datastore.

The only limit you might face is on the write side, where one entity group should not be updated more frequently than once per second.

Comment: Does that mean that my 25,000 scripts would all be server at nearly the same time?

Comment: If you make the requests at nearly the same time, you will receive responses at nearly the same time. If you want to queue them, however, you can do it using Task API. Also, if some requests read the same data, you can use Memcache instead of reading from the Datastore each time.

Comment: Wow that is amazing. I wont use Memcache because I put new data every 2mins. Thank you for your response

Comment: Memcache is much faster than Datastore and it's free. I would recommend using Memcache as long as you do more than 1 read of the same data before the next change, even if it changes every few seconds.

Comment: As long as you're not accessing the same key you're fine, there is a limit on read per entity, if you go above it, you'll get contention error. +1 for the memcache, you can invalidate the memcache entry when you write the entity.